# How to get the ID of an active link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to display the ID of the active link in my navbar through an alert, but I'm not sure how to do this with my current Bootstrap 3 classes.

I was thinking of something like

```
alert( $('li').hasClass( "active" ).attr('id') );
```

but sadly that doesn't work.

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/FdJHhA9Bxf)

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li class = "active"><a id = "tab1" href = "#" >Link1</a></li>
                        <li><a id="tab2" href = "#">Link2</a></li>
                        <li><a id = "tab3" href = "#" >Link3</a></li>

                    </ul><!-- END: "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" -->
                </div><!-- END: "container" -->
            </div><!-- END: "container" -->
</div><!-- END: "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" -->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to find the child of the `li` not the `li` itself, also why not use the class in the selector instead of using `hasClass`:

```
alert($('li.active a').attr('id'));
```

[See Demo](http://codepen.io/guyfedwards/pen/mADKu)

Comment: How come an alert isn't popping up for me? This is strange.

Comment: It's giving me "undefined" now.

Comment: Take a look at the demo

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
  alert( $('li.active a').prop('id') );
});
```