# How to keep the active link lit when clicking on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of buttons on my page, each of which calls a javascript function when clicked; when clicked, the active link color is lit, but when I click elsewhere on the page the active link color is cleared.  I want it to stay lit unless I click on another button link.

Here is an example of how a link is constructed (there are 10 links):

```
<div class="C1"><br><button class="button_01" onclick="HideDropdown(); ShowPage(7);">FAQs</button></div>
```

Here's the css for the button and C1 classes:

```
.button_01 {
    background-color: rgb(0,2,3);
    border: none;
    color: rgb(100,100,100);
    font-family: camphorW01-Thin,calibri,arial;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13pt;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 150ms ease-in;
}

.button_01:hover { color: rgb(175,222,162); }
.button_01:active { color: rgb(175,222,162); }
.button_01:focus { color: rgb(175,222,162); }
.button_01:visited { color: rgb(175,222,162); }

.C1{
    color:#DBDBDB;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14pt;
    text-indent: 0px;
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
}
```

I know the default behavior is for the active link color to clear when clicking elsewhere, but I should be able to use javascript or jquery to get the value of the active link and keep it the same color (unless I click on another link); I've found only two posts that come close but one is specific to list items (li), not a button class with an onclick handler (not an anchor tag) at [How to get the ID of an active link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276016/how-to-get-the-id-of-an-active-link).  Another post at [how to Keep the color of active link constant, until i press other link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025307/how-to-keep-the-color-of-active-link-constant-until-i-press-other-link) showed a jquery function specific to anchor tags; I modified it like this:

```
<script>
var items = $("button_01");
      items.removeClass("active");
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
<script>
```

That doesn't work and with that script in place the links do not work.

So my question is:  how do I keep the active link color lit on a button that has an onclick handler to call javascript (versus a list item or an anchor tag)?

Thanks very much for any help on this.

EDIT:  I solved this problem and posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

assuming all you buttons have `class="button_01"`

```js
$('.button_01').on('click', function(){
  $('.button_01').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button_01">Button 1</button>
<button class="button_01">Button 2</button>
<button class="button_01">Button 3</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk, but that removes the active link from the highlighted link and places it on the currently-clicked link, which is the default behavior.  What I need is something that keeps the active link lit when clicking anywhere BUT another link.

Comment: i might be missing something, the button you click will have the class active until you click another button of the same class

Comment: No, the default behavior is to clear when clicking elsewhere on the page -- that's for the active link color.

Comment: state `:active` is cleared, the class `.active` will remain

Comment: I'll try that because I'm currently using :active.  I'll Let you know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the .css() property within jquery if the active attribute is still clicking out on your site.

```
$('.button_class').on('click', function() {
$('.button_class').removeAttr('style');
$(this).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just made a quick fiddle with what I think is a possible solution to your problem. I've done in pureJs.

```js
function ShowPage(e,page){
  // do a function to reset colors to default
  resetColors();
  // call hide here, since you do it everytime you show a page
  HideDropdown();
  e.classList.add("active");  
  //do stuff here
}

function HideDropdown(){
  // do stuff here
}

function resetColors(){
  // do stuff here
}
```

```css
.active{
  color: red !important; 
}
```

```html
<div class="C1">
  <button class="wathever" onclick="ShowPage(this,7);">A</button>
  <button class="wathever" onclick="ShowPage(this,7);">B</button>
  <button class="wathever" onclick="ShowPage(this,7);">C</button>
  <button class="wathever" onclick="ShowPage(this,7);">D</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After much research and work, here's how I solved this problem.

Remember that I have 10 links, each with a unique ID number, so I loop through them 1-10 and create the ID name (e.g., btn04).  In order to keep the current active link lit, I have to change the link color to the active link color when I click anywhere on the page except for another link of the same type (button_01 class).  For that, I need to store the active element in a global var on each button click, so that on any subsequent click we know what the last active element was BUT the subsequent click will change the active element to the currently-clicked element.  What to do?  I set up another global var, LastActiveElement, which captures the most recently set active element.  Now I know where the last click was -- if it was a hyperlink and the current click is not a hyperlink, I change the last clicked hyperlink color back to its active color, which has the effect of keeping it on the same color.

Add this to the body tag:

```
<body onload="ShowABC(1);" onclick="changeColor(event); getLastGAE(event); getFocusElement(event);">

<script>
function changeColor(event) {

  for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    ID_Name = "btn0" + i.toString();
    if (i >= 10){ID_Name = "btn" + i.toString();}

    var elem = document.getElementById(ID_Name);

    TargetClass = event.target.getAttribute('class');
    TargetID = event.target.getAttribute('id');
    var active = document.activeElement;
    var equal = (LastActiveElement == ID_Name);
    tfh = TargetID == "hamburger_container";

    if ((equal == "true") && (TargetClass != "button_01") && (tfh == "false")){
        var newColor = "rgb(175,222,162)";
        elem.style.color = newColor; }
    if (TargetClass == "button_01"){ elem.style.color = "rgb(100,100,100)"; }
    if (TargetID == ID_Name){ elem.style.color = "rgb(175,222,162)"; }
  }
}
</script>

<script>
var LastActiveElement;
    function getLastGAE(event) {
    LastActiveElement = GlobalActiveElement;
}
</script>

<script>
var GlobalActiveElement;
    function getFocusElement(event) {
    var active = document.activeElement;
    TargetID = event.target.getAttribute('id');
    GlobalActiveElement = TargetID;
}
</script>
```

With that, if I click anywhere on the page except another hyperlink of the same class, the active link color does not change.

Now I know some advise against global vars, but this is only two data elements added to the DOM so it takes up negligible space.

Of course, there may be other solutions but this is what I came up with.

Thanks to everyone who replied to this question.